# Feedback on foodplatform-order schema

Tags: mysql

I'm making a platform similar to Just Eat, Takeaway or Uber Eats. On the platform, different restaurants can list their menu and users can order items from the restaurant's menu.

I have made a sketch of the database schema to save the orders of a user.
[image: Database schema foodplatform]

Each restaurant has several `Dish`es like e.g Pizza Margherita, Pizza Quattro Fromage, or Pizza Hawaii. Every dish has a variation, you could order a small, medium, or large pizza. The base price for each dish is saved in the `DishVariation`-table because the size decides the price.
The user can optionally also select 'extra items' like olives or more cheese for each dish (`DishExtra`). Each extra has its own price which will be added to the base price of a dish.

When the User orders a dish, I save in the table `Order` which user ordered it, from what restaurant at what time. Each order has one or multiple `OrderLines`. Each `OrderLine` represents an ordered dish.

`OrderLine` saves what dish and what variation of that dish were ordered together with the price at the time of purchase. `OrderDishExtra` functions to store the 'extras' selected for the specific dish in the linked order. Also, the price at the time of purchase is stored for each DishExtra.

With this schema, I can always retrieve the prices the User has paid to show them on his invoice. This is while the Admin is able to update the prices of his products.

Is this a good schema for my scenario? Any feedback?

Comment: Sketch out the `SELECTs`.

Comment: 1. Dump the `Id`s, there are not keys.  Keys first, then you can add surrogates where necessary. 2. You're not close to the solution which requires a lot of deep dives - how much time are you willing to invest and/or can you narrow your question to one specific area of design?